# как изменять содержимое тега style

Tags: javascript

Хочу изменять содержимое тега `style` через javascript, но что-то не идёт.
Я добавляю тег `style` в `.content` и хочу, чтобы применились стили для `.content` которые я написал в `input`

```js
function getElemWithClass(tag, ...className) {
  const node = document.createElement(tag);
  className.forEach((_className) => {
    node.classList.add(_className);
  });
  return node;
}

function createStyle(content) {
  let style = content.querySelector('.my__style');
  if (style !== null) {
    style.remove();
  }
  style = getElemWithClass('style', 'my__style');
  content.prepend(style);
  return style;
}

const content = document.querySelector('.content');
const input = document.querySelector('.input');

input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  const value = e.target.value;
  const style = createStyle(content);
  style.cssText = value;
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.input {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input">

<div class="content">
  <div class="block">
    1
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Введите  `.block{color:black;}`.

```js
function getElemWithClass(tag, ...className) {
  const node = document.createElement(tag);
  className.forEach((_className) => {
    node.classList.add(_className);
  });
  return node;
}

function createStyle(content) {
  let style = content.querySelector('.my__style');
  if (style !== null) {
    style.remove();
  }
  style = getElemWithClass('style', 'my__style');
  content.prepend(style);
  return style;
}

const content = document.querySelector('.content');
const input = document.querySelector('.input');

input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  const value = e.target.value;
  const style = createStyle(content);
  style.innerText = value;
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.input {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input">

<div class="content">
  <div class="block">
    1
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: не подскажите, а как сделать так, чтобы то, что в теге `style` влияло только на дочерние элементы?

Comment: @МихаилКамахин Я не понимаю вопрос.

Comment: я хочу, чтобы эти стили применялись только для блоков, которые внутри `.content`

Comment: @МихаилКамахин `style.innerText = '.content ' + value;`